# Mesh path from gzserver to gzclient

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I got the same issue for two interns, they can't load gzclient without an error about the 3D files not found with the path on the gzserver on a remote server. Both of them use roslaunch files to start . They use a custom version of husky robot and hector_quadcopter. The URI of each stl file is correct and I enforce the env variables gazebo_model_path and gazebo_media_path.

Very strange.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25610/mesh-path-from-gzserver-to-gzclient/) by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The client receives only the model descriptions, and not the mesh files. Also, URIs are paths on the remote server. So, if a model says that a mesh is installed in path A on the remote server, it needs to also be installed in path A on the local machine. Otherwise, the client fails to load the models.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on 2020-08-18**:
Thanks for your reply, we will deal with it